# Relation between mpmath and scipy: Type Error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mpmath

Scipy have a lot of special functions, in particular Bessel functions `jn` (always denoted by uppercase letter J_n(x)) and spherical Bessel functions `spherical_jn` (denoted by lowercase letter j_n(x)). On the other hand mpmath have `quadosc`, a special method for integrate rapidly oscillating functions, like `jn` and `spherical_jn`. *The problem I had obtained is that seems that* `quadosc` *from mpmath not support, e.g, `jn` from scipy as an input to make this integral*. I means, if I use `quad` imported from numpy, so nothing error of TypeError is obtained,  but `quad` is not very appropriate to evaluate integrals of J_n(x) or j_n(x) when x is very large.

(***) In the site [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/mpmath/calculus/integration.html#oscillatory-quadrature-quadosc) find by "Oscillatory quadrature (quadosc)", this example come from there.

```
from mpmath import findroot, quadosc, inf, j0

j0zero = lambda n: findroot(j0, pi*(n-0.25)) # ***
I = quadosc(j0, [0, inf], zeros=j0zero)
print(I)
I = 1.0 # OK, this is the correct answer.
```

But if I use J_n(x) imported from numpy:

```
from scipy.special import jn

f = lambda x: jn(0,x)
j0zero = lambda n: findroot(f, pi*(n-0.25))
II = quadosc(f, [0, inf], zeros=j0zero)
print(II)
```

then I got the following error (Edited: added the Traceback)

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpmath/calculus/optimization.py in findroot(ctx, f, x0, solver, tol, verbose, verify, **kwargs)
    927  try:
--> 928   fx = f(*x0)
    929    multidimensional = isinstance(fx, (list, tuple, ctx.matrix))
<ipython-input-449-aeebd9a1e908> in <lambda>(x)
      2 
----> 3 f = lambda x: jn(0,x)
      4 j0zero = lambda n: findroot(f, pi*(n-0.25))

TypeError: ufunc 'jv' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-449-aeebd9a1e908> in <module>
      3 f = lambda x: jn(0,x)
      4 j0zero = lambda n: findroot(f, pi*(n-0.25))
----> 5 II = quadosc(f, [0, inf], zeros=j0zero)
      6 print(II)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpmath/calculus/quadrature.py in quadosc(ctx, f, interval, omega, period, zeros)
     998   # raise ValueError("zeros do not appear to be correctly indexed")
     999   n = 1
 -> 1000  s = ctx.quadgl(f, [a, zeros(n)])
    1001  def term(k):
    1002  return ctx.quadgl(f, [zeros(k), zeros(k+1)]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpmath/calculus/optimization.py in findroot(ctx, f, x0, solver, tol, verbose, verify, **kwargs)
    929     multidimensional = isinstance(fx, (list, tuple, ctx.matrix))
    930     except TypeError:
--> 931     fx = f(x0[0])
    932     multidimensional = False
    933     if 'multidimensional' in kwargs:
```

On the other hand, if I use `quad` then I got

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

f = lambda x: jn(0,x)
III = quad(f,0,inf)[0]
print(III)
III = -21.154674722694516 # What is an incorrect answer.
```

So how can I use a function `jn` that come from scipy inside a `quadosc` of mpmath? How can I fix this error? Thanks for all help.

Comment: Since you don't use `jv` directly, show the traceback so we can see where the error occurs.  I suspect mpmath is passing its own class of numbers to the scioy.numpy function, which it cannot handle.

Comment: Thanks, I added the traceback. Yes, my question is there exist some way of make mpmath understand scipy functions.

Comment: It is important to say that I tested `jn` and `jv`  scipy function for the case n=v=0, that is, `jn(0,x)` and `jv(0,x)` and both are the same function.

Comment: yes, looking at the `jn` docs, I see that that's another name for `jv`.

Comment: Initially I wanted to understand why the error said `jv` when you called `jn`.  That's cleared up.  The problem is that `quadosc` passes `mpmath` numbers to the `jn` function, which can only use `C` doubles (or equivalent floats).

Comment: Yes, but this is not the problem, even if I change of `jn` to `jv` the problem persist and I got the identical error. The problem is that quadosc not understand `jn` (or `jv`) as an integrand. So if there exist some way of make mpmath and scipy communicate between, then quadosc can be applied for a large class of special functions, specially oscillating functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [31]: one,two = mpmath.mpmathify(1), mpmath.mpmathify(2)                     

In [32]: one,two                                                                
Out[32]: (mpf('1.0'), mpf('2.0'))

In [33]: one+two                                                                
Out[33]: mpf('3.0')

In [34]: jn(1,2)                                                                
Out[34]: 0.5767248077568736

In [35]: jn(one,two)                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-ec48c25f686b> in <module>
----> 1 jn(one,two)

TypeError: ufunc 'jv' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

`mpmath` numbers cannot be use in `jn/jv`.

In the same way, a `mpmath` number can be used in a `mpmath` function, but not the equivalent `numpy`:

```
In [41]: mpmath.sin(one)                                                        
Out[41]: mpf('0.8414709848078965')

In [42]: np.sin(1)                                                              
Out[42]: 0.8414709848078965

In [43]: np.sin(one)                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'mpf' object has no attribute 'sin'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-38fc918b311a> in <module>
----> 1 np.sin(one)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type mpf which has no callable sin method
```

You can convert the mpmath normal python number with:

```
In [44]: float(one)                                                             
Out[44]: 1.0

In [45]: jn(float(one),float(two))                                              
Out[45]: 0.5767248077568736
```

`np.float64(one)` also works, but `jn` does not like `np.float128(one)`.  Evidently `jn` has been compiled for C doubles, but not higher precision floats.

Does `mpmath` does talk about using it with `numpy`?  I've seen `mpmath` used with `sympy`, but not with `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use `scipy.special.jv` without converting its arguments to floats/integers.