# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, scipy, typeerror, mpmath

I need to make an integral of the type g(u)jn(u) where g(u) is a smooth function without zeros and jn(u) in the Bessel function with infinity zeros, but I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

First I need to change of variable x to variable u and make an integration in the new variable u but how the function u(x) is not analytically invertible so I need to use interpolation to make this inversion numerically.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

x = np.linspace(0.1, 100, 1000)
u = lambda x: x*np.exp(x)
dxdu_x = lambda x: 1/((1+x) * np.exp(x))               ## dxdu as function of x: not invertible
dxdu_u = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(u(x), dxdu_x(x)) ## dxdu as function of u: change of variable
```

After this, the integral is:

```
from mpmath import mp

def f(n):
    integrand = lambda U: dxdu_u(U) * mp.besselj(n,U)
    bjz = lambda nth: mp.besseljzero(n, nth)
    return mp.quadosc(integrand, [0,mp.inf], zeros=bjz)
```

I use `quadosc` from `mpmath` and not `quad` from `scipy` because `quadosc` is more appropriate to make integral of rapidly oscillating functions, like Bessel functions. But, by other hand, this force me to use two different packges, `scipy` to calculate `dxdu_u` by interpolation, and `mpmath` to calculate the Bessel functions `mp.besselj(n,U)` and the integral of the product `dxdu_u(U) * mp.bessel(n,U)` so I suspect that this mix of two different packages can make some issue/ conflict. So when I make:

```
print(f(0))
```

I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-ac2976a6b736> in <module>
     12     return mp.quadosc(integrand, [0,mp.inf], zeros=bjz)
     13 
---> 14 f(0)

<ipython-input-38-ac2976a6b736> in f(n)
     10     integrand = lambda U: dxdu_u(U) * mp.besselj(n,U)
     11     bjz = lambda nth: mp.besseljzero(n, nth)
---> 12     return mp.quadosc(integrand, [0,mp.inf], zeros=bjz)
     13 
     14 f(0)

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: dtype('O')  means you have an array of objects. I presume mp.quadosc returns some form of multiprecision type which is unrecognizable by numpy

Comment: Yes, I guess that this is the point.  What I don't know is if exist some way of make mpmath and numyp communicate with each other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440969/relation-between-mpmath-and-scipy-type-error

Comment: When `numpy/scipy` functions use compiled code, the numeric inputs have to be C compatible `doubles`.  `mpmath` objects are not doubles.  `numpy` doesn't 'know' anything about `mpmath`, so you really can't make them communicate, except by converting the `mpmath` objects to conventional numbers.

Comment: @hpulj indeed, nice find! The problem here is simpler though, since the mpf/double issue happens in the interpolation

Answer (score 2):

The full traceback (the part you sniped) shows that the error is in the `__call__` method of the univariatespline object. So indeed the problem is that the mpmath integration routine feeds in its `mpf` decimals, and scipy has no way of dealing with them.

A simplest fix is then to manually cast the offending part of the argument of the `integrand` to a float:

`integrand = lambda U: dxdu_u(float(U)) * mp.besselj(n,U)`

In general this is prone to numerical errors (mpmath uses its high-precision variables on purpose!) so proceed with caution. In this specific case it might be OK, because the interpolation is actually done in double precision. Still, best check the results.

A possible alternative might be to avoid mpmath and use the `weights` argument to `scipy.integrate.quad`, see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) (scroll down to `weights="sin"` part)

Another alternative is to stick with mpmath all the way and implement the interpolation yourselves in pure python (this way, `mpf` objects are probably fine since they should support usual arithmetics). It's likely a simple linear interpolation is enough. If it's not, it's not too big of a deal to code up your own cubic spline interpolator.

Answer (score 0):

The full traceback:

```
In [443]: f(0)                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-443-6bfbdbfff9c4> in <module>
----> 1 f(0)

<ipython-input-440-7ebeff3611f6> in f(n)
      2     integrand = lambda U: dxdu_u(U) * mp.besselj(n,U)
      3     bjz = lambda nth: mp.besseljzero(n, nth)
----> 4     return mp.quadosc(integrand, [0,mp.inf], zeros=bjz)
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mpmath/calculus/quadrature.py in quadosc(ctx, f, interval, omega, period, zeros)
    998         #    raise ValueError("zeros do not appear to be correctly indexed")
    999         n = 1
-> 1000         s = ctx.quadgl(f, [a, zeros(n)])
   1001         def term(k):
   1002             return ctx.quadgl(f, [zeros(k), zeros(k+1)])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mpmath/calculus/quadrature.py in quadgl(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
    807         """
    808         kwargs['method'] = 'gauss-legendre'
--> 809         return ctx.quad(*args, **kwargs)
    810 
    811     def quadosc(ctx, f, interval, omega=None, period=None, zeros=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mpmath/calculus/quadrature.py in quad(ctx, f, *points, **kwargs)
    740             ctx.prec += 20
    741             if dim == 1:
--> 742                 v, err = rule.summation(f, points[0], prec, epsilon, m, verbose)
    743             elif dim == 2:
    744                 v, err = rule.summation(lambda x: \

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mpmath/calculus/quadrature.py in summation(self, f, points, prec, epsilon, max_degree, verbose)
    230                     print("Integrating from %s to %s (degree %s of %s)" % \
    231                         (ctx.nstr(a), ctx.nstr(b), degree, max_degree))
--> 232                 results.append(self.sum_next(f, nodes, degree, prec, results, verbose))
    233                 if degree > 1:
    234                     err = self.estimate_error(results, prec, epsilon)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mpmath/calculus/quadrature.py in sum_next(self, f, nodes, degree, prec, previous, verbose)
    252         case the quadrature rule is able to reuse them.
    253         """
--> 254         return self.ctx.fdot((w, f(x)) for (x,w) in nodes)
    255 
    256 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.py in fdot(ctx, A, B, conjugate)
    942         hasattr_ = hasattr
    943         types = (ctx.mpf, ctx.mpc)
--> 944         for a, b in A:
    945             if type(a) not in types: a = ctx.convert(a)
    946             if type(b) not in types: b = ctx.convert(b)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mpmath/calculus/quadrature.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    252         case the quadrature rule is able to reuse them.
    253         """
--> 254         return self.ctx.fdot((w, f(x)) for (x,w) in nodes)
    255 
    256 

<ipython-input-440-7ebeff3611f6> in <lambda>(U)
      1 def f(n):
----> 2     integrand = lambda U: dxdu_u(U) * mp.besselj(n,U)
      3     bjz = lambda nth: mp.besseljzero(n, nth)
      4     return mp.quadosc(integrand, [0,mp.inf], zeros=bjz)
      5
```

at this point it starts using the `scipy` interpolation code

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py in __call__(self, x, nu, ext)
    310             except KeyError:
    311                 raise ValueError("Unknown extrapolation mode %s." % ext)
--> 312         return fitpack.splev(x, self._eval_args, der=nu, ext=ext)
    313 
    314     def get_knots(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py in splev(x, tck, der, ext)
    366         return tck(x, der, extrapolate=extrapolate)
    367     else:
--> 368         return _impl.splev(x, tck, der, ext)
    369 
    370 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py in splev(x, tck, der, ext)
    596         shape = x.shape
    597         x = atleast_1d(x).ravel()
--> 598         y, ier = _fitpack._spl_(x, der, t, c, k, ext)
    599 
    600         if ier == 10:

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

`_fitpack._spl_` probably is compiled code (for speed).  It can't take the `mpmath` objects directly; it has to pass their values as C compatible doubles.

To illustrate the problem, make a numpy array of `mpmath` objects:

```
In [444]: one,two = mp.mpmathify(1), mp.mpmathify(2)                            
In [445]: arr = np.array([one,two])                                             
In [446]: arr                                                                   
Out[446]: array([mpf('1.0'), mpf('2.0')], dtype=object)

In [447]: arr.astype(float)    # default 'unsafe' casting                                                     
Out[447]: array([1., 2.])
In [448]: arr.astype(float, casting='safe')                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-448-4860036bcca8> in <module>
----> 1 arr.astype(float, casting='safe')

TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

With `integrand = lambda U: dxdu_u(float(U)) * mp.besselj(n,U)`,

```
In [453]: f(0)      # a minute or so later                                                                
Out[453]: mpf('0.61060303588231069')
```